# EF DbContext disposal

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm having more than usual sleeping connections in my server and I was wondering if this piece of code could be causing the dbContext to remain open since I have an if statement that returns not letting the code to be fully executed.

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDBContext())
{
    if(SomeStatement)
    {
        return;
        db.Dispose(); // Should I dispose it here?
    }
} //the dbContext supposed to be disposed here.
```

-If SomeStatement is true, will the code return without closing the current db connection?
-Should I dispose it inside the If statement?

Thanks.

Comment: `using` statements are compiled to a `try` `finally` block where the object is disposed in the `finally`. It will be disposed regardless of what you do.

Comment: The "sleeping" connections could be from the connection pool. `DbContext` normally [does not even need to be disposed](https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/)

Comment: Both comments make a lot of sense I just don't understand why my sleeping connections could be growing to much lately. I have max of 250 connections allowed and usually my server  has 100-120 sleeping connections since we have several queries coming in from different programs. Lately this is growing to the Max 250 making the server to throw  too many connections error.